# Extracting date from filename in AWS S3

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a  file named `F1_2017_01_23.txt` in Aws S3. From S3 i have to load the data into redshift.

Requirement: S3 is having 10 columns and redshift is having 11 columns (basically 1 column extra). As per the name of the file (mentioned above) i have to extract the date from the file and load into redshift 11th column.

Can you please help me how to extract the file name from S3, so that I can populate the last field in redshift.?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this directly with Redshift.

You'll need to either edit the file before loading it into Redshift, or perform an UPDATE operation to modify this field after loading. For example, UPDATE any row where that field is currently empty. This would need to be run as a subsequent command after the COPY command.

There's a vague chance you could use NULLAS to insert a value that is specified with the COPY command.